# I am using jhipster with MongoDB. How to design entity with jhipster jdl for complex data structure (nested JSON)

Tags: jhipster

I have complex JSON structure with arrays.Please let me know if there is way to design entity in JDL studio for same.

Below is an example of JSON I'd like to have generated. Keys in the JSON are dynamic.

```
 {
  "_id" : ObjectId("71testsrtdtsea6995432"),
  "HotelName": "Test71testsrtdtsea699fff",
  "Description": ".....",
  "Address": {
    "Street": "....",
    "City": "....",
    "State": "...."
  },
  "Rooms": [
    {
      "Description": "......",
      "Type": ".....",
      "Price": "....."
      "Availability": [
            true,
            false
          ]
    },
    {
      "Description": "......",
      "Type": "....",
      "Price": "..."
      "Availability": [
            true,
            false
          ]
      "newDynamickey": [
            {}
          ]
    },
  ]
  "AdditionalData": [
    {
        "key1": "Vlaue1",
        "key2":"Value2"
    },
    {...}
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There shouldn't be any problem with creating that structure with JDL Studio. Just use `ManyToMany` and `ManyToOne` relationships for your Arrays and everything should be alright.